# Как работают сокеты?

Tags: сокеты

Пытался разобраться в работе сокетов на примере питона. Не понятны следующие моменты. Простите если вопросы слишком глупые.

1. Есть три стадии серверного сокета:

   1. Привязан к порту
   2. Прослушивает
   3. Принимает подключения
      если просканировать порт на этих стадиях. Как он будет выглядеть? Будет закрыт пока не разрешить подключение? Зачем тогда стадия прослушки?
2. Обект сокета создается функцией socket.socket() но в мануалах также пишут что sock.accept() возвращает адрес клиента и новый сокет. В какой момент бы создан сокет? Если я закрою сокет я его уничтожу или только разорву текущее соединение. Актуально и для TCP и для UDP? Можно ли будет подключиться повторно?
3. Функция listen() принимает аргументом колличество подключкений в очереди. После первого подключения, при попытках подключения других клиентов их добавят в очередь. Как это будет выглядеть на стороне клиента? Их очередь наступит. Пока не передаются данные? Или только когда разоровеся соединение с первым? Актуально и для  TCP и для UDP

Answer (score 1):

1. стадия "прослушивания" - это не стадия. с помощью listen сокет переводится в специальное прослушивающие состояние. и для клиентов он как бы "готов к работе".

> если просканировать порт на этих стадиях.

все зависит от того, что Вы понимаете под сканированием и какие инструменты используете. Я вижу, что в вопросе идет упор на nodejs (или что то очень похожее), но при этом нигде больше этого не видно.

2. Когда создается "серверный/слушающий сокет", то он просто принимает входящее соединение. Это его предназначение. Но для работы с клиентом (обменом данными), уже используется другой сокет (назовем его рабочим клиентским сокетом), который возвращает accept. После этого слушающий сокет готов снова принимать подключения клиентов. То есть, новый сокет создается в момент между подключением клиента и завершением accept.

Поэтому, если закрыть слушающий сокет, то сервер просто не сможет принимать новых подключений, но все уже подключенные клиенты смогут продолжить работать. Если закрыть клиентский сокет, то просто будет разорвано соединение с текущим клиентом, не более.

Так как это все основывается на установлении соединения, то это все относится только к TCP. У UPD другие правила.

> Можно ли будет подключиться повторно?

если закрыть слушающий сокет, то подключится никак не получится - никто не слушает новых соединений. А если клиентский, то без проблем, если сервер может и хочет подключить клиента, то он это может сделать.

3.

> После первого подключения, при попытках подключения других клиентов их добавят в очередь. Как это будет выглядеть на стороне клиента? Их очередь наступит. Пока не передаются данные?

"запрос на соединение" будет поставлен в очередь. И когда до него доберется accept, клиент будет подключен. Со стороны клиента это выглядит так - запрос на подключение отправил, нет ответа от сервера, как будет connect немного затормозил.

> Или только когда разоровеся соединение с первым?

А это зависит от устройства Вашего приложения. В больших приложениях один поток забирает через accept соединение, а потом либо создает для него отдельный поток (старая модель, но иногда очень хорошая, когда будет не много клиентов, но они тяжелые) либо добавляет сокет в некий пул потоков на обработку, либо использует мультиплексирование ввода (select/poll/epoll/e.t.c). Но есть и простая реализация, когда сделали accept сокету и работаем с клиентом. Завершили, закрыли, делаем accept следующему. Такая модель проста, но если с клиентом работают долго, то все остальные будут ожидать.

> Актуально и для TCP и для UDP

в случае UPD нет установки соединения, там нечему делать accept. И если есть "сервер", который по upd ожидает много клиентов, то он может пользоваться одним сокетом и работать со всеми. Такие сервера часто значительно проще, позволяют работать в один поток.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Многое прояснилось. 
1. Значит я могу закрыть рабочий клиентский сокет, так же как и слушающий, вызвав close() для объекта возвращенного close()?
2. Как мне тогда принять подключение для нескольких клиентских сокетов на одном слушающем? Допустим просто последовательно вызывать accept()? По типу:
conn, addr = sock.accept()
conn2, addr2 = sock.accept()
должен ли я  тогда как-то разбирать на какой именно из клиентских сокетов я отправляю/принимаю данные если они привязаны к одному порту?

Comment: 3. Получается если мы хотим получать данные от двух клиентских машин и управляем сокетами, потоками или при помощи select(), это подразумевается для двух клиентских сокетов на одном слушающем? Правильно я понимаю что два клиентских сокета на одном слушающем одновременно принимать данные не могут. И если не создать для каждого поток или не переключаться между ними select-том, то сами они не будут этого делать.

Comment: после того, как слушающий сокет через accept выдал Вам клиентский сокет, он не имеет никакого к нему больше отношения. Поэтому, принимайте через accept всех, добавляйте в какой-то массив и обрабатывайте.
а сокеты можно закрывать тогда, когда они не нужны.